# How to check all characters in word a in word b (C lang)?

Tags: c, comparison

I want to check if every character in word A is also in word B.
This function doesn't work yet, but I hope you can help me anyway.
I created a check variable which only increases if the character at the position i in word A is equal to the character i in word B.

```
int is_equal(char *a, char *b)
{
    int i = 0, j;
    int check = 0;
    while (a[i] != '\0')
    {
        for (j = 0; b[j] != '\0'; j++)
        {
            if (a[i] == b[j]) //Here
            {
                i = i + 1;
                j = 0;
                check = check + 1; //Increase
            }
            else
            {
                i = i + 1;      
                j = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    if (check % strlen(a) == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the end of this function I'm gonna check if check % length of string a is 0.
And if that's the case, every character in A is also in B. 
But it doesn't work because if a[i] and b[j] aren't equal, j is going to be reset to 0 and it crashes. So, how can I fix this? How can I reset the loop to check from the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you make a decision on whether or not a character from `a[]` matches anything form `b[]` inside the nested loop. This is too early for that decision, because your code did not have an opportunity to check other characters in `b[]`.

You can modify your code to introduce a `found` flag, set it to zero before going into the nested loop, and then setting it to 1 if you find a match:

```
int found = 0;
for (j = 0 ; !found && b[j] != '\0' ; j++) {
    found = a[i] == b[j];
}
```

The value of `found` after the loop indicates if any of the characters in `b[]` match `a[i]`.

**Note:** This works well for short `a[]`s and `b[]`s, but for very long strings it could be too slow. A better approach is to walk `b[]` once, mark all chars in it, and then walk `a[]` to check if any characters are missing:

```
int seen[256] = {0};
for (int i = 0 ; b[i] ; i++) {
    // Mark characters from b[]
    seen[(unsigned char)b[i]] = 1;
}
for (int i = 0 ; a[i] ; i++) {
    // Found a char in a[] that's not in b[]
    if (!seen[(unsigned char)a[i]]) {
        return 0;
    }
}
return 1;
```